# Expansion of (delayed) environment vars in a FOR

Tags: batch-file

why does !doit! not expand to its value inside the FOR loop?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /ad /s') do (
     pushd "%%~I"
     set doit=yes
     if not exist *.f* (
       if not exist *.c* set doit=no
     )

     if "!doit!" == "yes" FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR *.f* *.c* /B /A:-D /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%G
     popd
)
```

When  I run this I see that !doit! is not expanded:

...

if "!doit!" == "yes" FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('DIR *.f* *.c* /B /A:-D /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%G

...

Comment: Delayed Expansion is done *after* command echoes, so you cannot see the expanded values there; to check the values, do `echo/!doit!` (temporarily)...

Comment: You may get better mileage by setting `doit` to *nothing* or `a value` (any value). `if defined doit ...` uses the run-time value of `doit`, so `delayedexpansion` may not need to be used.